# How should I add a custom property to a rails helper method?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I have a Rails helper method...

```
  def current_user
    @user = User.find(cookies[:user_id]) if cookies[:user_id]
  end
```

And I want to add a non-database property to it...

```
self.custom_property = true
```

So I can access it in my view.

```
<%= current_user.custom_property %>
```

But, Rails says "Undefined method: custom_property"

Here's the full code:

```
  def current_user
    @user = User.find(cookies[:user_id]) if cookies[:user_id]

    @user.ribbon_array ||= []
    self.is_moderator = @user.ribbon_array.include?(1) ? true : false
  end
```

I'd like to do it like this so in my view I can check current_user.is_moderator. Elsewhere in my code I have an @is_moderator variable that's specific to each page, but this one would be used across the whole app and specific to the current_user as opposed to the user on the profile.

Comment: @Joshua Scott answer is the best. However, if you want to share why are you trying to do this, maybe we can help you figure out a better way?

Comment: @fotanus sure, I'll edit the post.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Edit**

My bad without too much thought. In this case maybe a better solution is to add another helper method. Helpers themselves are not so object oriented, so you should be able to tolerate this kind of solution as well.

```
def current_user
  @current_user = User.find(cookies[:user_id]) if cookies[:user_id]
end

def is_moderator?
   ribbon = @current_user.ribbon_array || []
   ribbon.include?(1)
end
```

Comment: This seemed like it would work but returned `undefined local variable or method `current_user' for ApplicationController:Class`.

Answer (score 1):

To accomplish this

> I'd like to do it like this so in my view I can check
>   current_user.is_moderator. Elsewhere in my code I have an
>   @is_moderator variable that's specific to each page, but this one
>   would be used across the whole app and specific to the current_user as
>   opposed to the user on the profile.

I recommend you to implement a method on your user model called

```
def is_moderator_of(page)
    # returns true or false here
end
```

Or better yet, use a authorization gem like [cancan](https://github.com/ryanb/cancan)

EDIT:

Also, this

```
@user = User.find(cookies[:user_id]) if cookies[:user_id]
@user.ribbon_array ||= []
```

will generate "Method not found: ribbon_array for nil" if there is no cookies[:user_id]

Answer (score 0):

In your app/models/user.rb file:

```
class User << ActiveRecord::Base
  attr_accessor :custom_property
  ...
end
```

Then your view code should work.

Alternatively, you could just set @custom_property = true in the helper, and use @custom_property in the view.

Comment: It still gives me `undefined method 'is_moderator=' for #<ChallengesController:0x007f9373170aa8>`

Comment: Because you are running self.is_moderator in the controller?  You would run current_user.is_moderator.